# Junit hibernate-validation error

Tags: spring, hibernate, junit, hibernate-validator, spring-test

I'm using Hibernate-validator annotations in my Entities and this causes an exception in my Junit tests.
If I disable the hibernate validation with the property:

```
<prop key="javax.persistence.validation.mode">none</prop>
```

Then the Junit test works very well otherwise I receive the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or     abstract in class file javax/el/ExpressionFactory
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.<init>(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:169)
at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.<init>(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:118)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.<init>(ConfigurationImpl.java:110)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.<init>(ConfigurationImpl.java:86)
at org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator.createGenericConfiguration(HibernateValidator.java:41)
at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:276)
at javax.validation.Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory(Validation.java:110)
at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.getValidatorFactory(TypeSafeActivator.java:445)
at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.activate(TypeSafeActivator.java:96)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator.integrate(BeanValidationIntegrator.java:148)
... 61 more
```

The JUnit test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:spring-config-test.xml")
@Transactional
public class BaseTest {

    @Test
    public void init () {
      Assert.assertEquals(15,15);
    }
}
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute ...

indicates that you use an jar that contains only the class and method signatures but not the method implementation.

Often is cause is that one use `javaee-api.jar` from http://download.java.net/maven/2/.

Remove this jar! (and when needed, replace it with the right jars that contains the code)

@See http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/java-lang-classformaterror-absent-code-attribute-in-method-that-is-not-native-or-abstract-in-class-file/